# same lines of code but giving different result

Tags: python

```py
N = int(input("Enter How many times you want to print the number of times you want to print the stars:\n "))
for i in range (n,0,-1):
for j in range (n-i):
print (' ', end='')
for j in range (2*i-1):
print('*',end='')
print ()
```

```py
row = int(input('Enter number of rows required: ')) 
for i in range(row,0,-1):
for j in range(row-i):
print(' ', end='') # printing space and staying in same line
for j in range(2*i-1):
print('*',end='') # printing * and staying in same line
print() # printing new line
```

please tell me the difference between the both codes

Comment: Can you explain what this code is and why you're asking? What's the expected result and what are you actually getting? Give us some context, please.

Answer (score 1):

You named the variable in the first one "N" instead of "n". Also there's an extra loop in the first one but I don't think that's what you're asking.

```
N = int(input("Enter How many times you want to print the number of times you want to print the stars:\n ")) 
for i in range (n,0,-1): 
    for j in range (n-i): 
        print (' ', end='') 
        for j in range (2i-1):
            print('',end='') 
            print ()

row = int(input('Enter number of rows required: '))
for i in range(row,0,-1): 
    for j in range(row-i):
        print(' ', end='')
```

Oh, and turn your text into code by wrapping it in ```